# Uploading files with HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using the HTML5 multiple-file attribute to allow users to upload multiple images at a time. It works great, except with large images. I know how to change the MAX_FILE_SIZE value in my html. I changed it to "5000000". Now, the photos from my iPhone are large, anywhere from 2.0 MB-5.0 MB. When I try to do multiple of these large images, it doesn't work. Now, with multiple smaller size images, it works fine. I know it's not the MAX_FILE_SIZE associated with my form because these large images will upload individually. So, my question is, is there a Limit to the total size of the FILES being uploaded at one time? If so, how do I change it? Is it PHP or HTML?

Also, can I re-size these photos on upload, so they aren't so big?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` ini settings, it also might be limit setting in your web server. About resizing - its another question look at [imagick thumbnailimage method](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.thumbnailimage.php)

Answer (score 0):

Search for the php.ini on the server side and look for
**upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** and increase their value to whatever is needed to get your images up,